# MySQL INNER JOIN is slower than LFET JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have an impression on that Inner join is always faster but in my data set it seems to be very slow compared to LEFT JOIN. Can you please help me to understand why it's so if I use the below query.

```
select   
A.id,C.name 
from      
table1 A    
INNER JOIN table2 B    ON B.ID = A.ID     
INNER JOIN table3 C ON B.crid=C.ID   
Where A.user_id =704 
AND B.starttime  >=  '2019-10-01 00:00:00' 
AND B.starttime  <= '2019-10-01 23:59:59';
```

The table1  and table2 have 15 million records and table3 has got only 130 records.

The LEFT JOIN will show up the result in 4 sec while INNER JOIN takes almost 4 min.

Thank you,
Peter

Comment: Please show the result of [`EXPLAIN EXTENDED`](https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/06/15/explain-extended-can-tell-you-all-kinds-of-interesting-things/) and the query [`profiles`](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/mysql/query-profiling/) for both! Also, critical, please provide the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_x\G`. The more information you provide, the more help you can receive!

Comment: ... and specify, does both JOINs are altered to LEFT or only one of them (and which).

Answer (score 0):

- `LEFT JOIN` says that the *right* table is optional.
- You have tests for columns in `A` and `B`.  So `FROM A LEFT JOIN B` will actually be turned into `INNER JOIN` because `B` is not really optional.
- The keywords `INNER` and `OUTER` change *nothing* in MySQL.
- There is no `WHERE` requirement for C.  So the `JOIN C` is *not* the same as `LEFT JOIN C`.
- You *may* get fewer rows of output with `JOIN C` than with `LEFT JOIN C`; in the latter case, `C.name` will show as `NULL` for the extra rows.  Because of this, I would expect the opposite of what you said, namely that `LEFT JOIN C` would be slower.
- That leads to an alternative way to write the query:

  ```
  SELECT ...,
      ( SELECT name FROM C WHERE ... ) AS name,
      FROM ...  ((Leaving out the " JOIN C ON ..."))
  ```
- Since there are `WHERE` clauses for both `A` and `B`, the Optimizer will have to guess which table to start with.  Use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see which way it will be done.  Probably one of the `WHERE` clauses filters better, but *perhaps* the Optimizer does not guess right, thereby leading to different performance.  (Note, this has nothing to do with your question about speed of `LEFT`.)
- Indexes (usually) are the most important factor in performance.
- (Unrelated)  It is usually bad schema design to have 1:1 mappings (`ON B.ID = A.ID`).  The question comes up: "Can't they be a single table?"
- I am assuming that `ID` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of each table, and you are using InnoDB??
- *The following analysis is heavily dependent on the exact query; if you "simplified" the query, my recommendations may not be valid!*
- Optimal indexes when starting with `A`:

  ```
  A: INDEX(userID, ID)  -- handles WHERE; is covering (assuming query is complete)
  B,C: ( PRIMARY KEY(id) will suffice )
  ```
- Optimal indexes when starting with `B`:

  ```
  B: INDEX(starttime, crid, ID)
  A,C: ( PRIMARY KEY(id) will suffice )
  ```